# Как вывести количество людей в каждом департаменте SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть две таблицы SCOTT.EMP и SCOTT.DEPT

Нужно вывести количество людей, в каждом департаменте(dname)
Пробовал по этому коду, но ничего не вышло, не могу понять где ошибка

```
SELECT ename, dname, deptno
FROM SCOTT.EMP ee
JOIN SCOTT.DEPT dd ON dd.deptno=ee.deptno
WHERE ename IN (SELECT COUNT(deptno) FROM SCOTT.EMP)
```

Comment: " Пробовал по этому коду," --- а что это а код? Какой-то эльфийский язык.

Comment: Например это `WHERE ename IN (SELECT COUNT(deptno) FROM SCOTT.EMP)` --- что это происходит можете сами себе объяснить?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский _что это происходит_, понятно же, верни все имена, которые только что посчитал. Новая семантика, приближена к человеческому языку ))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
    SELECT dname, COUNT(ename) AS CNT
    FROM SCOTT.EMP ee
    JOIN SCOTT.DEPT dd ON dd.deptno=ee.deptno
    GROUP BY dname
```